# checkbox not working when opening a navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a nav menu like this...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="">Groups <b class="caret pull-right"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="display: block;">
            <li class="filter">
                <a href="#" style="padding:8px 20px;">Filter</a>
                <div class="src-key">
                    <form action="/dev/admin/products" class="flex-search" role="form" id="ProductAdminIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                        </div>  <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
                        <input type="text" id="group-fill" class="src-prod ui-autocomplete-input" name="data[Product][info]" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="hidden" name="data[Product][track]" value="g">
                        <input type="hidden" id="group-id" name="data[Product][group_id]">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <li>
                <div class="scrlr">
                    <ul class="all-grps">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/1">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="1">Sample Group 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/2">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="2">Sample Group 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/3">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="3">Sample Group 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/4">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="4">Sample Group 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/5">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="5">Sample Group 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/6">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="6">Sample Group 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/7">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="7">Sample Group 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/8">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="8">Sample Group 8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/9">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="9">Sample Group 10</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/dev/admin/products/index/g/10">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][id]" id="10">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the checkbox then the check and un-check not working. I need to check multiple options from the list.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/ZF52d/) checkbox is working fine without any css rules apply. Maybe your css causing this. Can you put you CSS code instead for that menu? Thanks.

Comment: I used bootstrap3.x navigation menu..

Comment: try add z-index:9999 (optional value) to the checkbox style. Here the fiddle using bootstrap cdn css http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/ZF52d/ still no problem with the checkbox

Comment: @Nucleo ..no impact by adding z-index...

Comment: Can you put the CSS code here on in that fiddle ? or do you have link to test with firebug ?